# Become Facebook-fan through cached Facebook-widget

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, wordpress

I've been using the official fan box widget for a while on my blog and wanted to replace it with a cached version of the widget which loads much fewer content.

The widget (for Wordpress) works pretty well (http://www.electriceasel.com/plugins/plugin-facebook-fan-box-cache) however one thing bugs me.

The "I like"-button just links to the Facebook-fanpage so the user would've to click again on "become a fan" which makes no sense since the user would expect to already be a fan after the first click.

What I'm looking for are solutions for either of these two problems:

1.) Find a way for users to become a fan with the cached plugin-version directly

2.) Reduce all the crap Facebook loads for the widget. It adds two seconds to my pages loadtime which isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the author of the plugin, I need to say, this is probably the MOST requested feature. I'm working on a solution to this, but I also must note that the purpose of the plugin was to remove all external JS files to speed up loading. I'm looking into a very small JS script that I could utilize to get this working as requested, but haven't been able to to this point. Reference the blog post you linked to for further updates.

Answer (score 1):

you probably don't want to cache the facebook code as you'd have no way to know when it was changed/updated. This code will load the script without blocking the page. It may take 2 seconds for your like buttons to show up but it will prevent the slow loading you describe.

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```